# unresolved dependency for postgresql 9.2 jar in play framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, dependency-management, postgresql-9.2

I am using postgresql 9.2 with play framework 2.1

I downloaded the driver here:  http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html (JDBC4 Postgresql Driver, Version 9.2-1002)

My `project/Build.scala` file is as follows:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val appName = "myApp"
  val appVersion = "0.1"

  val appDependencies = Seq(
    "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.2-1002.jdbc4")

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies)
}
```

I have placed the jdbc driver in the following locations in the play directory structure:

```
myApp/lib/postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.jar
myApp/lib/9.2-1002.jdbc4.jar
myApp/lib/postgresql/postgresql/9.2-1002.jdbc4.jar
```

However, running the app with `play run`, I get the following error and the build fails:

```
[warn]  module not found: postgresql#postgresql;9.2-1002.jdbc4              
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/ubuntu/play-2.1.0/repository/local/postgresql/postgresql/9.2-1002.jdbc4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== Typesafe Releases Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/postgresql/postgresql/9.2-1002.jdbc4/postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe Snapshots Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/snapshots/postgresql/postgresql/9.2-1002.jdbc4/postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/postgresql/postgresql/9.2-1002.jdbc4/postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                       
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: postgresql#postgresql;9.2-1002.jdbc4: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: postgresql#postgresql;9.2-1002.jdbc4: not found
```

---

**Any tips on how to get the Play! to recognize my jar file?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The 9.2 version of Postgresql driver [has not yet hit the Maven central repo](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22postgresql%22%20AND%20a%3a%22postgresql%22), so you'll have to use the 9.1 version :

```
"postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901-1.jdbc4"
```

Or you can use the 9.2 version by dropping the JAR in your `myApp/lib` folder and remove any dependency from your `project/Build.scala` file (the `lib` folder is automatically added by sbt).

Comment: Yep, silly me.  I need to remove the dependency from `Build.scala` if I want to include it manually in `myApp/lib`.  Cheers

Answer (score 13):

I have found this in the  [Repository](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.postgresql%22%20AND%20a%3A%22postgresql%22):

```
"org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.2-1003-jdbc4"
```

Comment: The newer versions are also there

Answer (score 1):

When I change 9.2 version to 9.1 version, it works perfectly. Thanks for your answer nico_ekito

My buid.scala

```
  val appDependencies = Seq(
  "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901-1.jdbc4",
  jdbc,
  javaCore,
  javaEbean
  )
```

My application.conf

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/DBName"
db.default.user=postgres
db.default.password=123456
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using the information at the following link:

https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg/issues/1

I hope you find it useful!! :)

good luck ;)

linixinil.

Comment: Please describe the solution here -- do not just point to a URL.

Answer (score 0):

In file **application.conf**:

```
 db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
 db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dataBaseName"
 db.default.user=user
 db.default.password="password"
```

create the pasta **/lib** in your main project and should add the **.jar** do postgres.

Download [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22postgresql%22%20AND%20a%3A%22postgresql%22), and after reload the project.